# How can I plot cyclic data with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I want to plot a curve with `geom_line()` of a cyclic curve (several y values for 1 x). Here is the code I used :

```
library(ggplot2)
Donnees<-read.delim("~/Desktop/DSC.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\t",dec=".")

DSC<-ggplot(data=Donnees,aes(x=V3,y=V4))+geom_line()

print(DSC)
```

I obtained the following plot, where the y of a same x seem connected by a line.

[image]

But, I would like a plot like this one, easily obtained from the exact same data with excel.

[image]

Would you have any advice?

Thank you

Comment: It would really help to have sample data. Can you post a representative sample with `dput(x)`?

Comment: Sample data would be super helpful. But it looks like this should be fairly simple to do by creating a new variable that tracks whether your value is positive or negative and then passing it to the `group` variable in your `aes` function. I'm sure someone can help if you supply the output of `dput(Donnees)`.

Comment: You'll probably also need to use `geom_path` instead of `geom_line`, which connects observations in order of `x`, instead of order of appearance. If you have a loop and use `geom_line` it will tend to look like your error, as the line gyrates between the top and bottom parts of the series.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I simply used `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()` and it works :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.